# How to read csv to dictionary with multiple values?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I want to read data like below into like this:

```
{
  'a' : ['row1,'row2','row3'], 
  'b' : ['row1,'row2','row3']
}
```

| columns A | columns B |
| --- | --- |
| a | row1 |
| a | row2 |
| a | row3 |
| b | row 1 |
| b | row 2 |
| b | row 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(FILE) as file:
    contents = [row for row in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')]
data = {
    'a': [row['columns B'] for row in contents if row['columns A'] == 'a'],
    'b': [row['columns B'] for row in contents if row['columns A'] == 'b']}

data
# >> {'a': ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], 'b': ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3']}
```

Tested with Python3, but should work with Python2 as well. If not, please let me know.